# Adding a side scroll bar to a table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have Tried searching for Codes about Scroll bar but I am not quite sure, how I am Supposed to input the codes and I could not find a suitable code for my project.
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POu5m.jpg)

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/kn2WF here is the link of the images that i am unable to upload

Comment: @halfer Can you assist me please? :)